# Opening image and text file with the same name

Tags: matlab

My problem is that I have a folder containing some images namely a.jpg, b.jpg, and so on, and have another folder containing text files a.txt, b.txt, and so on. I will select one image like `a.jpg` is selcted then along with image the text file `a.txt` is also displayed. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extract the file name (e.g. `'a'`) from the full-file name (e.g., `'a.jpg'`).
To this end you can use `fileparts` command that can split `'a.jpg'` into `'a'` and `'jpg'` for you.

Please read the documentation of [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) for more information.